# LUIS - Publish to production and staging

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

Can someone guide me how to publish the `LUIS` models to `staging`, `production` environment. Also how do I consume the `staging environment` `LUIS` in development environment.

Answer (score 0):

This LUIS doc specifically discusses [how to publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-publish-app) to production and staging and should tell you what you need to know.

As for what is consumed, that depends on the environment you have published to (first image) and which you selected as active (second image).

When you click the "Publish" button, you are presented with this option. It is here you decide which environment you want to publish to. The tested and ready LUIS app would be published to Production while the in-development LUIS app would be published to Staging.

[image]

The version you select and mark as active is the one that will be used.

[image]

Hope of help!